# Cordova Firebase Analytics and Custom Url Scheme

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, cordova-plugins, ionic3

I have an Ionic 3 application. I have installed the following [plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Custom-URL-scheme)
I have everything setup from the instructions, and able to use any custom scheme that I setup. I have the following code that will simply alert the URL I pass through to the app -

```
(<any>window).handleOpenURL = ( url ) => {
    alert( url );
};
```

I wanted to introduce [Firebase analytics](https://github.com/chemerisuk/cordova-plugin-firebase-analytics) into the app. As soon as I do this, the above function for the custom URL scheme no longer works. If I remove the Firebase plugin, it works again.

Can anyone help me or come across anything like this before? Might be worht noting this is only an issue on iOS

Comment: I am having the same problem ,, Were you able to get this issue resolve

Comment: No wasn't able to solve it. I think it is down to the entitlements but it's a little beyond my capability - I went with GA plugin and that serves what I need at the moment. I do hope to one day revisit this and solve it however

Comment: Hello! Can you enable URL Schemes, i can't make it work on iOS, thank you in advance